# Release repository Cleanup

Tags: open-source, nexus

We are using Nexus OSS 3.0.2-02 version which doesn't have option to clean up the release repository.

In earlier version (2.5) Nexus OSS had rest API to clean up release repository along with the out-of-box scheduled jobs to housekeep the release repository.

Do we have any option to cleanup the release repository in OSS 3.0.2-02? Also if the latest version (of OSS 3.6) has any option to clean up the release repository?